# How whatsapp handle APNS notifications even if the app was not launched?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

So I am trying to handle the APNS notification even if the app was not launched in iOS,Same like in whatsapp...But ended with failure...Can anyone explain how i can archive this ?

Comment: All apps (Including Whatsapp) need to launch and ask for Push notifications and save device token once , after that push notification can be sent regardless of the state of app.

Comment: "after that push notification can be sent regardless of the state of app." Thats incorrect - an app that has been terminated will not receive a push.

Comment: @BhumitMehta Please compare a APNS Push notification in Whatsapp...Whatsapp will receive notifications even if the app was not launched...I just wonder how they did that ?

Comment: @SausageModulationMatrix Any idea regarding this ?

Comment: whatsapp uses voip pushes. I've not used them myself, but I'm sure a voip push must have to be launched once in order to start receiving them . Are you sure if you uninstall the app, then re-install it and don't start it then it can still receive pushes> I have to say I am very very very skeptical about,  I can't believe any app could receive any type of push or similar without running at least once.

Comment: @SausageModulationMatrix I had founded the solution but if i use Voip permission in my app which is doesn't have VOIP features,It will be rejected in the App Store

Comment: Is your problem resolved? then close this question.

Comment: @Hasya How to close this question ?

Comment: @radkrish accept any answer which helped you. So it will close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PushKit (VoIP notification) to achieve this. App should be launched once after that regardless of state of the app notification will appear on device. For this type of notification, app will not ask user confirmation about sending notifications.

Answer (score 1):

PushKit can be send to send notification for VOIP app which will silently launch app even if it is terminated by user.

Answer (score 0):

When you download app from app store and don't launch then you cant have push notification.

Try this

- Keep distribution certificates
- Edit scheme
- Select "Wait for executable to be launched"
- Now run app in device
- Keep debug pointer on didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Your app will install on device, send push notification it will not come ( Because app not registered for APNS, device token did not reached to server ).

Now tap on app debug pointer at didFinishLaunchingWithOptions will become active, let appDelegate to do rest of work, now send push notification it will come ( Because app is now registered for APNS, device token also reached to server ).

Using pushkit is different thing, would not help you to get push notification without launching an app.